# Outbound rules for location header rewrite not working in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting

I have an Asp.Net MVC hosted in Azure that is behind a reverse proxy. The proxy is not re-writing the outbound content based on the host so I'm doing it myself in the web.config of the azure website. I have an outbound rule that is working:

```
<rule name="ChangeReferencesToOriginalUrl" 
      preCondition="CheckContentType" 
      stopProcessing="true">
  <match filterByTags="None" 
         pattern="http://azurewebsiteapp.azurewebsites.net" />
  <action type="Rewrite" 
          value="https://www.domaininfrontofproxy.com" />
</rule>
```

The only problem is I need to also update the response headers. This rule for response headers is not working and I have no idea why:

```
<rule name="ChangeLocationHeader" 
      stopProcessing="true">
  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" 
         pattern="^http://[^/]+/(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" 
         pattern="^302" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" 
          value="https://www.domaininfrontofproxy.com/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Any help would be appreciated